# How to set currency as non-USD when redirected to paypal page

Tags: c#, html, sql, paypal

I have table name Courses in MS SQL. It has price. I mean price as Singapore Dollar (SGD). I am integrating with Paypal. Everything is working fine until webpage is redirected to paypal when user clicks on "Buy Now" image on Courses table. How can I achieve my Price data in table Courses are SGD, not USD. The problem is that I am not sure where to fix. Should I have to fix in html or c# code or sql or javascript or all of the above? In my sandbox, I have configured my currency as SGD. I have tried with globalization uiculture="es-US" culture="es-SG" in Web.config  as well as in html. None of them is working. Please advise how I can go about it.
Thank
Joe

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain in more detail how you say you have configured the currency in your sandbox?  Is it programmatic or a setting somewhere in PayPal Developer?  I admit I've nev. er actually developed with the PayPal API, though I've poked around it a bit.  However, I can say pretty confidently that *it won't be* a matter of incorrect localization, since you should be able to configure the currency regardless of your location.

If you're using classic API, take a look at the `PAYMENTREQUEST_n_CURRENCYCODE` field in this doc: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/

If you're using the REST API (which seems more likely- check out the request example in this section: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#create-a-payment  The `transactions` list in the JSON payload for the request can contain multiple `amount` objects, which have a `currency` property that accepts a three letter currency code. Hope that helps any.

ETA: so then to answer the question you actually closed with, it seems like the place to make changes would be your JavaScript or maaaybe your C# code, depending on how your page is set up--wherever you're generating API calls.  It's possible I've misunderstood your actual use case, however.  Either way, the API documentation would be the place to look.